# Axis2 "No WS-Security header found"

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, axis

I'm trying to use axis2, but there must be Security headers in message.

I tried to add PEWSClientHeaderHandler class from [this example](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v4r5m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/process_java_api/guide/web_services/ws_usage_headers.htm), but it doesn't work (it works with default sun implementation, but not with axis2). The formed SOAP message looks like this:

```
...
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"></wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
...
```

UsernameToken, Username and Password tags are missing (but again, they are set in code and no exception when using sun).

Can anyone provide the simplest example of how such a header can be set in axis2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis2 implementation has 1 little difference:

Standard Sun implementation:

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();

SOAPHeader sh = envelope.addHeader();
SOAPElement wsSecHeaderElm = soapFactory.createElement("Security", AUTH_PREFIX, AUTH_NS);
SOAPElement userNameTokenElm = soapFactory.createElement("UsernameToken", AUTH_PREFIX, AUTH_NS);
SOAPElement userNameElm = soapFactory.createElement("Username", AUTH_PREFIX, AUTH_NS);
SOAPElement passwdElm = soapFactory.createElement("Password", AUTH_PREFIX, AUTH_NS);

userNameElm.addTextNode("username");
passwdElm.addTextNode("password");

userNameTokenElm.addChildElement(userNameElm);
userNameTokenElm.addChildElement(passwdElm);
wsSecHeaderElm.addChildElement(userNameTokenElm);
sh.addChildElement(wsSecHeaderElm);
```

Axis2 implementation:

```
// the same as above

userNameTokenElm.addChildElement(userNameElm);
userNameTokenElm.addChildElement(passwdElm);
SOAPElement el = sh.addChildElement(wsSecHeaderElm); // addChildElement returns new SOAPElement!
el.addChildElement(userNameTokenElm);
```

That's all